# Keep value semantics on structs (containing an array of reference types)

Tags: swift, struct, value-type

Let's say (just as an example) I have a class *Person* and a struct *House*:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var lastName: String

    init(name: String, lastName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}

struct House {
    var address: String
    var squareMeters: Float
    var owner: Person

    init(withAddress address: String, squareMeters: Float, andOwner owner: Person) {
        self.address = address
        self.squareMeters = squareMeters
        self.owner = owner
    }
}
```

To keep the value semantics on *House* is pretty easy in this case, if I'm not mistaken I can just do something like:

```
struct House {
    var address: String
    var squareMeters: Float
    private var owner: Person //owner is now private

    init(withAddress address: String, squareMeters: Float, andOwner owner: Person) {
        self.address = address
        self.squareMeters = squareMeters
        //init now creates a copy of the owner passed
        self.owner = Person(name: owner.name, lastName: owner.lastName)
    }

    //every time the owner gets modified from the outside we make sure to create a copy if needed
    private var ownerToWrite: Person {
        mutating get {
            if !isKnownUniquelyReferenced(&owner) {
                owner = Person(name: owner.name, lastName: owner.lastName)
            }
            return owner
        }
    }

    var ownerName: String {
        get {
            return owner.name
        }
        mutating set {
            ownerToWrite.name = newValue
        }
    }

    var ownerLastName: String {
        get {
            return owner.name
        }
        mutating set {
            return ownerToWrite.lastName = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, this should work. But what if *House* contained an **array** of *Person*? For instance:

```
struct House {
    var address: String
    var squareMeters: Float
    var tenants: [Person]

    init(withAddress address: String, squareMeters: Float, andTenants tenants: [Person]) {
        self.address = address
        self.squareMeters = squareMeters
        self.tenants = tenants
    }
}
```

How could I maintain the value semantics on the new *House* struct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *maintain*? Do you think appending elements, etc.?

Comment: Nope, what "worries" me is (and probably I should elaborate the question further) this: someone could access, for instance, tenants[3] and modify it without the House to be actually copied and re-created and this is wrong. This wouldn't follow the struct value semantics (check the example I wrote here above with "owner" instead of "tenants". Every time the owner is modified we create a new owner to maintain the House value semantics).